# Why two objects of the Integer class with same value gives false on equality check when value is greater than 127?

Tags: java, class, object, oop, integer

```
class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer a = 5;
        Integer b = 5;
        Integer c = 129;
        Integer d = 129;
        System.out.println(a == b);
        System.out.println(c == d);
    }
}
```

The output is

> true
>
> false

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

When using Integer wrapper objects instead of the `int` primitive, java globally caches these objects in this range because they are used often. This can speed up execution. Because these objects are cached, they are equal, while above the threshold a new objects is created of every integer.

When you want to compare `Integer`s instead of `int`s use the `.equals()` method instead of `==`.

Comment: As a good rule of thumb, use `.equals()` for all *objects* (like `Integer`), and reserve the use of `==` for *primitives* (like `int`). This is because when `==` is used to compare objects it compares their references (roughly analogous to memory addresses), instead of their values.